# How can I programmatically change the report source of my report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, reportviewer

I have created a web application that displays different types of reports. So basically my parameter here is report style. the user will select a report style and then the the report will load according to the selected style.

So I created 7 different designs of report. my question is, how can I programmatically change the report source of my report viewer so that every time the user will select a different report style, the report viewer will call that report.

for example:

If I select STYLE A, the report viewer will load report1.
If I select STYLE B, the report viewer will load report2.
If I select STYLE C, the report viewer will load report3.
and so on...

Comment: I'm actually trying to use     ReportViewer1.ReportSource = StyleA_MainReport     But it's not working. I think I am missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring a variable that will accept the ReportStyle parameter. If your webservice has a parameter ReportStyle (String) declare this code on your Visual Basic code.

TypeReportSource - Represents a report source that allows a report document to be instantiated from an AssemblyQualifiedName.

Click [here](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/t_telerik_reporting_typereportsource.html) for more info.

```
Dim typeReportSource As New Telerik.Reporting.TypeReportSource()
Dim ReportStyle as String


if ReportStyle = "A" then
    typeReportSource.TypeName = GetType(SampleReport).AssemblyQualifiedName
    ReportViewer1.ReportSource = typeReportSource
end if
```

Note that the SampleReport is name of the Report you have created, this is named "Report1" by default.

Answer (score 0):

Hide /unhide elements on the report based on a parameter?

I had a few reports that would show all kinds of different data, and the user had a few parameters i would just hide the Tablix based on an expression.

Like this: parameter has a 3 options view a , b ,c

in tablix for view a go to properties and go to the visabilty menu and add and expression like

`Parameter!view.Value = a`

this will make the tablix visible.

You can do this for all the views and there repective dataset (just add @view = 'a' in the where clause to stop the query from exicuting when the parameter is not selected)

Hope this helps with the probelem